# Bootstraps ICheck-Helper does not trigger on changed event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have this Jquery code to be updating checkboxes base on whether a checkbox has been checked.  However, This does not fire.

**Code**

```
$('body').on('change', '.territory', function () {
    var PK = $(this).find('input:checkbox:first').val();
    var PKStr = '.parent' + PK;
    console.log('change!');
});

$('body').on('change', '.iCheck-helper', function () {
    //var PK = $(this).find('input:checkbox:first').val();
    //var PKStr = '.parent' + PK;
    console.log('change!');
});

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label">
      Selected Territories
    </label>
  </div>

  @for (int c = 0; c < 2; ++c)
  {
     int Count = 0; 
     <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
     @foreach (var ter in Infobase.MMS.Models.ComboBoxValues.GetTerritoryRights(0))
     {
        if (Count % 2 == c)
        {
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="territory" value="@ter.Key">
                                                        &nbsp;@ter.Value

          </label>
        }
        Count++;
      }
   </div>
  }    
</div>
```

I've tried binding to the click function and change function on iCheckbox-Helper as well as directly to the checkboxes. However neither seem to work.  Everything does work fine when I dont add in the Icheck.js script.

Does anybody know how to hook into on changed event from bootstraps Icheckhelper class?

Comment: According to [this issue for iCheck](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/68), this was a known issue. Although it claims that this was solved by a more recent update, I'm still having the issue. (I ran across your question while looking for a solution.) If you're still looking for a fix, perhaps try out some of the snippets in the comments on the issue.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use ifChanged or ifChecked mentioned in the [documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20141209203450/https://fronteed.com/iCheck/) (web archive version)

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Comment: link is dead :(

Answer (score 18):

I just added this globally and it does the trick for me.

```
$(".i-checks input").on('ifChanged', function (e) {
    $(this).trigger("change", e);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the jQuery Events the trigger the onClick Event

```
$('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').on('ifChanged', function (e) {
     $(this).trigger("onclick", e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me.

```js
$(document).on("ifChecked", "input", function () {alert("Changed");})
```